# How to check a transaction is successful or not, when executing UFT API Test in Load Runner

Tags: automated-tests, loadrunner, uft-api

I am using UFT 12.02 to create UFT API tests, the same tests i am using in Load Runner to check the transaction response time.

The challenge i am facing is to check for success and failure during execution. In Load runner we can easily check the response for different success indicators (e.g. response code '200 OK' or 'user ID' or 'Success ID' generated by the system) but in case of UFT API script we can add start and End transaction activities in the flow but cannot check the application status based on any indicator.

Please let me know if there is any way to check that the completed transaction is a pass transaction or a failure.

currently I am getting all transactions as passed but the records inserted in the DB are far less than the passed transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot set a fail / pass criteria when using LoadRunner transactions in UFT. All transactions are considered as finished with "passed" status. The core usage of UFT - LoadRunner transaction integration is to measure response times, nothing else.